# Pandas Inner Join with Lambda

Tags: python, pandas, join, lambda, inner-join

I have the following two frames:

frame1:

```
            id
0  111-111-111
1  111-111-222
2  222-222-222
3  333-333-333
```

frame2:

```
     data       id
0    ones  111-111
1  threes  333-333
```

And, I have a lambda function that maps the `frame1.id` to `frame2.id`:

```
id_map = lambda x: x[:7]
```

My goal is to perform an inner join between these two tables, but to have the id go through the lambda.  So that the output is:

```
            id    data
0  111-111-111    ones
1  111-111-222    ones
2  333-333-333  threes
```

I've come up with a rather non-elegant solution that *almost* does what I'm trying to do, however it messes up when the inner join removes rows:

```
# Save a copy the original ids of frame1
frame1_ids = frame1['id'].copy()
# Apply the id change to frame1
frame1['id'] = frame1['id'].apply(id_map)
# Merge
frame1 = frame1.merge(frame2, how='inner', on='id')
# Set the ids back to what they originally were
frame1['id'] = frame1_ids
```

Is there a elegant solution for this?

Comment: `frame1['id'] = frame1['id'].str.slice(7)`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's effectively what I'm doing with `frame1['id'] = frame1['id'].apply(id_map)`.  But it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @AaronNBrock: but it is more elegant, and way more efficient.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hum, good to know!  However, in the actual use case the lambda is much more of a mess than that, so it wouldn't work.  But thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could use `assign` to create a dummy id column (newid) to join on like this:

```
frame1.assign(newid=frame1['id'].str[:7])
      .merge(frame2, left_on='newid', right_on='id', suffixes=('','_y'))
      .drop(['id_y','newid'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
            id    data
0  111-111-111    ones
1  111-111-222    ones
2  333-333-333  threes
```

Comment: I had just come up with this & it does seem to work.  It would be nice if there was a `.merge(frame2, right_on=lambda x: x[:7])` where `x` is whatever `left_on` is set to

Comment: @AaronN.Brock Yeah, per the docs, `on` accepts a label or a list not functions :(